# index for very large table sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

i have a large table with 4 miliion rows , the problem is my select from that table with
special columns with a 3 month period is very slow and creating index,changing filegroup,changing datatypes
does not help for performance.
SO help me :D
thx by the way

table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table](
    [Datef] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [MasterT] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [SlaveT] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [AllT] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [SlavePrice] [float] NULL,
    [Exp] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Number] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [StoreNo] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Kind] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Code] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [TruePrice] [float] NULL,
    [StoreName] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
    [SumNo] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Price] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Qc] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [TF] [real] NULL,
    [MTF] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [MGP] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [GMK] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [MSNO] [int] NULL,
    [inx] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL,
    [Vazn] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Hjm] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Masir] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [kindj] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Maliat] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Avarez] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [IsMaliat] [bit] NULL,
    [PromotionNo] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [CashDis] [real] NULL,
    [TF1] [real] NULL,
    [MTF1] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [TF2] [real] NULL,
    [MTF2] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [TF3] [real] NULL,
    [MTF3] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [TF4] [real] NULL,
    [MTF4] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [kindj2] [tinyint] NULL,
    [kindj3] [tinyint] NULL,
    [kindj4] [tinyint] NULL,
    [PromotionInfo] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [CashDisO] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Dastmozd] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Sarbar] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([inx] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN dbo.t1.Kind = 'F' THEN N'SALE' ELSE N'returned' END AS Kind,
       t1.Code,
       t1.Name,
       t1.MasterT,
       t1.SlaveT,
       t1.AllT,
       t1.SlavePrice,
       t1.SlavePrice * t1.AllT AS Price,
       t1.TF,
       t1.MTF,
       t1.TF1,
       t1.MTF1,
       t1.TF2,
       t1.MTF2,
       t1.TF3,
       t1.MTF3,
       t1.TF4,
       t1.MTF4,
       ROUND(
                (((t1.AllT * t1.SlavePrice - t1.MTF) - t1.TruePrice * t1.AllT)
                 + (t1.Maliat + t1.Avarez)
                ) * -1,
                0
            ) AS AD,
       t1.Maliat + t1.Avarez AS Maliat,
       t1.TruePrice * t1.AllT AS TruePrice,
       t1.StoreNo,
       t1.PromotionInfo
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE t1.kind = 'f'
      AND t1.DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'
```

Comment: In the query displayed below, there is no filter on a date. You then work on your entire table if it is the right query. To improve your query, if not, add an date criteria. Then you can create a clustered index which include first the filed kind, the the date, and the real key. Can you display the query in the original post (not in an answer), and also display the table definition ?

Comment: Just curious why [Datef] is nvarchar and not a date .

Comment: To add to John Cappelletti's comment, using `table.date between 'date1' and 'date2'` will perform an _alphabetical_ comparison of the values. Are the date strings arranged so that they sort _nicely_, e.g. not `'7-DEC-1941'`?

Comment: Guys i know data types is verry very bad, help me to solve this problem ! John u just see datef type? See other data types like real and.... listen im not dba for this db but i must handle it

Comment: I'd bet if you just run the query with actual execution plan or display the estimated execution plan, SSMS will probably give you the covering index you need. Something like ```CREATE INDEX ix on table1([kind],[date]) INCLUDE(<all other columns in your select>```. Not much else you can do query-wise.  Any other slowness is due to your server and data structure, which are a bit harder to change

Comment: Aside... if you want to store the full range of bigint results from the identity function in your `inx` column you'll be wanting `numeric(19,0)` instead. But why not just use bigint? `numeric` 10-19 requires 9 bytes, which is odd to handle, whereas `bigint` requires only 8 bytes and is a native type for most (current) CPU architectures.

Answer (score 0):

A BTREE index on these two columns will allow this particular query. It tests for equality on `kind` and for a range on `DATE’, so you need

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX kind_date (kind, [DATE]);
```

You could also INCLUDE some other columns, but unless your query usually fetches many rows, that won't be worth the trouble.

Others have said it, but it bears repeating: dates stored in NVARCHAR  columns considered harmful.

Comment: Dear  o.jones , i wrote at the begin question , i did this things u said but it does not work... create index ix_asd on table kind,datef  include(other selected columns  )